# Excel - index match with skipping empty cells

Tags: excel

I can't figure out a formula according to the following [excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci5cW.png).
I match a column value with a row value and the intersecting value will show in the cell. This works with the following formula  `=IF(INDEX($C$3:$H$8;MATCH($K3;$B$3:$B$8;0);MATCH(L$2;$C$2:$H$2;0))=0;"";(INDEX($C$3:$H$8;MATCH($K3;$B$3:$B$8;0);MATCH(L$2;$C$2:$H$2;0))))`
But I would like to move to the next match if a cell is empty (to fill in the red cells which is shown in the attached excel sheet). It is an example sheet; the original one got a lot of duplicates in the verion value.

Looking forward to a reply!

Guido

Answer (score 0):

got it fixed
paste the following formula in cell C15 of the [excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roYhk.png)
`=IFERROR(INDEX(3:3;MATCH(1;INDEX(INDEX($2:$2=C$14;0)*INDEX(3:3<>"";0);0);0));"")`